# Changing font-family for placeholder

Tags: css, input, stylesheet, font-face, placeholder

Is it posible for an input field to have one `font-family` and it's placeholder another?

I have tried to change `font-family` for the input's placeholder with an already defined `@font-face` in CSS but it's not working:

**CSS**

```css
    .mainLoginInput::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
      font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .mainLoginInput:-moz-placeholder { 
      font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

**HTML**

```html
    <input class="mainLoginInput" type="text" placeholder="Username"  />
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it...

Prefix for Firefox 19+ users is `::-moz-placeholder`

And the code looks like this

```
.mainLoginInput::-moz-placeholder {
   font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}
```

Comment: There is also `::-ms-input-placeholder` if you support IE 10.

Answer (score 69):

In case someone want the placeholders selectors for all browsers :

```
.mainLoginInput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.mainLoginInput:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.mainLoginInput:-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.mainLoginInput::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why `-moz-placeholder` is added twice? (Maybe I don't understand these single `:` or double `::`.

Comment: The one with the single `:` is for firefox v18 and lower. They adopted the double version to follow the webkit semantic

Answer (score 9):

Use this for major browser support :

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder text.." class="mainLoginInput" />
```

**CSS:**

```
.mainLoginInput::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

.mainLoginInput:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.mainLoginInput::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Details reference [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp)

Answer (score 5):

Simply like this

```
.mainLoginInput::placeholder{
     font-family: -Your font here-;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete use of `::placeholder` pseudo-element:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
 color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
 color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
 color: pink;
}
```

All placeholders in Firefox have an opacity value applied to them, so in order to fix this we need to reset that value:

```
::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/)