# How to change placeholder font

Tags: css

I am currently trying to change the font of the placeholders for my User ID and Password fields. I added the css below which changes the User ID placeholder font but not the Password placeholder font and i'm not sure why.

Any help?

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-family: 'helveticaneueregular', sans-serif !important;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
      font-family: 'helveticaneueregular', sans-serif !important;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
      font-family: 'helveticaneueregular', sans-serif !important;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
      font-family: 'helveticaneueregular', sans-serif !important;
}
```

```html
 <input style="font-family: 'helveticaneueregular', sans-serif !important;" type="text" id="username" name="username" role="textbox" class="rememberMainField txt15 commonFont1Style2 clearTextField" placeholder="User ID" required="" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" aria-label="Enter Your User ID" maxlength="50" minlength="3" pattern="^[^ ]+$" relinputid="RelativeClass0">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing font-family for placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524328/changing-font-family-for-placeholder)

Answer (score 1):

More info? It works for both in this example:

```css
.font1::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.font2::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
Times New Roman placeholder font:<br/>
<input class="font1" placeholder="User ID">
<input class="font1" type="password" placeholder="Password">
<br/><br/>
Arial placeholder font:<br/>
<input class="font2" placeholder="User ID" >
<input class="font2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```