# Change the font size of the placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the font size of the placeholder. So I included font size in the below classes but it's not changing.

Can you tell me how to fix it so that in future I will fix it myself.

Providing my codesnippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/61183rqp3w

```
 cssLabel: {
    "&$cssFocused": {
      color: purple[500],
      fontSize: 14
    }
  },
  cssFocused: {},
  cssUnderline: {
    "&:after": {
      borderBottomColor: purple[500],
      fontSize: 14
    }
  },
  cssOutlinedInput: {
    "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: purple[500],
      fontSize: 14
    }
  },
  notchedOutline: {},
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing font-family for placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524328/changing-font-family-for-placeholder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve your target, you must change the input styles properties in InputProps, as an example:

note: this will show ... if the placeholder overflow.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  input: {
    "&::placeholder": {
      textOverflow: "ellipsis !important",
      color: "blue",
      fontSize: 14
    }
  }
});
```

and

the component should be:

```
<TextField
  InputProps={{
   classes: {
     input: classes.input
   }
  }}
  variant="outlined"
  placeholder="Exp. XXXXXXXXXXXX"
/>
```

please find the code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/9j479w189y

Comment: hey its working...can you tell me how you fixed it so taht in future I will fix it myself

Comment: without giving textoverflow also its working...can you tell me why we need textoverflow

Comment: Can you please choose this as the correct answer so others can take benefits from this. Text-overflow is used if the placeholder text longer than the text box then '...' sign will be applied. And to fix the question as I did you need to go through the documentation in here: material-ui.com/api/input. there you can find the CSS API. in addition to that input has placeholder selector. ( that's how I override it)

Answer (score 0):

for change the **placeholder style** you may use this code :

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}
```

source: [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/)